# How to replace the elements in a big sparse matrix?

Tags: matlab, replace, sparse-matrix

I have quite a big sparse matrix, about 150,000*150,000. I need to access into its rows, extract the non-zero elements and replace these values following the rule as as the code below:

```
H = [];
for i = 1: size(A,2)
    [a,b,c] = find(A(i,:)); % extract the rows
    if size(c,2)==1  % only 2
        add = 0;
    elseif size(c,2) > 1 && any(c<2)== 0 % many 2s
        add = c;
        add(1)   = -2;
        add(end) = 2;
        add(2:end-1) = 0;
    elseif size(c,2) > 1 && any(c<2)~= 0 % 2 and 1
        k = find(diff(c)==-1); % find right 2 position
        add = c;
        add(1)   = -1;
        add(end) = -1;
        add(k) = 2;
        add(2:k-1) = 0;
        add(k+1:end-1) = 0;
    end
    %add = diff([0 c(2:end) 0]); % the replacing rule
    aa = i*ones(1,size(a,2)); % return back the old position of rows
    G0 = [aa' b' add']; % put it back the old position with replaced values 
    H = [H; G0];    
end
```

The rule is

- Keep the element 2 on the very right in the row
- The first and last elements in the row are replaced by -1
- All other elements become 0.
- In case there is just only one element 2, it will be replaced by 0.
- In case there are two or more 2s, the very right one will remain and
  the very left one will be replaced by -2, the middle elementsare replaced by 0.

and here is the figure that visualises these rules
[image]

The left figure is non-zero elements of rows extracted from the sparse matrix and I want the output to be like the right figure. I just selected some examples to explain the rules.

I did ask a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45653799/how-to-deal-with-nonzero-elements-from-rows-of-sparse-matrix-in-matlab) and got a wonderful answer. The rule was differences between 2 adjacent elements in the row so that it could be integrated into the `accumarray` function. But in this case, the rule is a bit different and I don't know how to perform this task quickly. The sparse matrix is quite big so the `for` loop is a terrible thing to do here.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't think the rules you've described match the images you've given

Comment: I think I was not very clear about the case there are more than two elements 2 in the row, so I just edited. Hope that it is clear now. Thank you very much

Comment: It is still too broad, I have edited the question to make your criteria much clearer but you need to be showing what sort of thing you've tried etc. For instance how would you do it if your matrix was only the size of the example, not 150,000^2 elements

Comment: I see, I will try with a small matrix from now then. Many thanks @Wolfie, really appreciate that!

Comment: Feel free to edit your question to include additional information or code which may help others to answer your question.

Comment: You should try to show what have you tried to solve the problem. If time is an issue, I also suggest reading the data from the matrix, deleting it, and creating a new one. Perhaps its faster than modifiying values on it

Comment: yes @AnderBiguri, I've just added the code that describes what I could think of.  Can you explain clearer about ""creating a new one" as you said? I think this is what I am doing. The previous post wasn't clear so you might misunderstand?

Comment: @chappi accessing element by element a sparse matrix is time expensive. Regarthlees on how to change the values, perhaps its better to get all values, then modify them as you please, and then create a new sparse matrix. This may be faster than modifiyng the elements of the matrix itself.

Comment: yes @AnderBiguri, I think that is what I am doing here or at least trying to avoid the for loop. The answer in my previous question as I have just edited, did help to get all the values as you said. But the thing is that I dont know how to changes the values followed by the rules  and still keep the same positions of the old spare matrix.