# How to integrate conditions in a MATLAB anonymous function?

Tags: matlab, function, if-statement, anonymous

My below code is quite time consuming because of a quite big A matrix (150,000^2). Can I integrate the conditions as a function `@(x)` in `accumarray`? So that I can work on the cell-based for all the rows `b` without having to convert into `double` and apply the condition? I think it will be much faster ! Thank you very much !

```
tic
[a b c]=find(A.'); %extract the positions of non-zero elements of A
add_sym=accumarray(b,c,[],@(x){x}); % re-arrange the values of same row b
add_r = [];
for i = 1:size(add_sym) % go through every row to check the conditions
    r = vertcat(add_sym{i})';  % inverting cell into double vector
    if size(r,2)==1  % and apply the 3 conditions for each row
        add_r0 = 0;
    elseif size(r,2) > 1 && any(r<2)== 0 % many 2s
        add_r0 = r;
        add_r0(1)   = -2;
        add_r0(end) = 2;
        add_r0(2:end-1) = 0;
    elseif size(r,2) > 1 && any(r<2)~= 0 % 2 and 1
        k = find(diff(r)==-1); % find right 2 position
        add_r0 = r;
        add_r0(1)   = -1;
        add_r0(end) = -1;
        add_r0(k) = 2;
        add_r0(2:k-1) = 0;
        add_r0(k+1:end-1) = 0;
    end    
    add_r = [add_r; add_r0']; % saving the replaced values as vectors
end   
ADD = sparse(b,a,add_r,nm,nm,nzmax); % put it back to the same position of sparse matrix A (with replaced value)

toc
```

This code is written for the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813822/how-to-replace-the-elements-in-a-big-sparse-matrix?noredirect=1#comment78588942_45813822)

Comment: Can you add a [mcve]? It would make it much easier to time excecution and try out your code, without comments it's hard to see what it does in the first place.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I did add the comments, hope it is clearer. I can upload the matrix, but I can not find where I can insert a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, you are looping over the rows of the sparse A matrix. Instead of converting to cells and back, it is probably more convenient to explicitly extract the rows and do your checks. My attempt:

```
% dummy A, contains 0, 1 or 2's at random
N = 1e4;
A = sparse(randi(2,[N,N])); % A contains 1's and 2's
A(rand([N,N])<0.8) = 0; % randomly delete 80%

tic
add_r = zeros([nnz(A),1]);
iter = 0;
for n=1:size(A,1)
    tmp = A(n,:);
    iter_incr = nnz(tmp);
    if iter_incr==1 % no need to set add_r element to zero
        %
    elseif iter_incr>0
        if ~any(tmp(tmp>0)<2)
            add_r(iter+1) = -2;
            add_r(iter+iter_incr) = 2;
        else
            add_r(iter+1) = -1;
            add_r(iter+iter_incr) = -1;
            add_r(iter+find(tmp(tmp>0)==2)) = 2;
        end
    end

    % increment
    iter = iter + iter_incr;
end
toc
```

This runs in about 20 seconds on my laptop, I had to kill your solution after several minutes. Note that I was unable to test for larger matrices at the moment, this is a 10000 by 10000 matrix, and probably does not resemble the structure of your data well.

Comment: Yes, it is much faster indeed. Thank you very much. But did you notice that add_r change its size at the end, not nnz(A) anymore ?

Comment: so that I dont really know to put form back the new sparse matrix ADD with replaced values

Comment: you are right, I've updated the answer (the `find` statement read `find(tmp==2)` before).

Comment: Yes, it works now, really quick !! just a little tiny issue that the condition any(tmp<2) seems not work somehow. It doesn't seem to recognize the second conditions, where [2 2] --> [-2 2] or [2 2 2] --> [-2 0 2] and so on [2 2 2 2] --> [-2 0 0 2]. I've tried to understand the way you code, but still not luck

Comment: Ah, the `tmp` also contains the zeros, so you would need to change that line into `any(tmp(tmp>0)<2)`.

Comment: it did solve the second conditions, but somehow affect to the third conditions, where [ 1 2 2 1] --> [-1 0 2 -1]  or [1 2 2 2 1] --> [-1 0 0 2 -1]. The left and right edges are replaced by -1, and the last 2 in the row remains the same, meanwhile the rest is zero. Really appreciate your attempt !

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want to achieve in the final condition, i.e. the definition of `k` in your attempt. Probably you can enter something along the lines of `add_r(diff(tmp(tmp>0))==-1) = 2` with the other statements

Comment: k is the position of the last 2 in the row ! Yes, I agree that it is not that clear at all but you did find it out ! Finally I could get the way you did it. Just a tiny change from "add_r(iter+find(tmp(tmp>0)==2)) = 2;" to "add_r(iter+find(diff(tmp(tmp~=0))==-1)) = 2;" and it works great ! Many thanks !!!